# How to make cpanel send an e-mail when disk usage goes over quota?

Tags: cpanel, quotas

I am hosting a few websites on a hosting account with 6 GB of space. The websites occupy only about 700 MB. But I have some plugins with various troubles generating error_log files that can get pretty big.

The last error_log had 4 GB and my quota jumped over a few days ago.

So is there a way to make cpanel send me an e-mail when quota goes over a set value?

Should I made a cron job for that?

Comment: Thanks to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909786/how-to-get-disk-space-usage-and-monthly-bandwidth-transfer-from-cpanel-to-my-webs/ I have found a PHP class for cPanel API here  http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3534-PHP-List-and-manage-details-of-cPanel-hosting-accounts.html ,and since nobody gave me any points I'll made a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for...

In cPanel on Contact Information & Preferences you can setup an email and then check "Send notifications to your contact email address when you are reaching your disk quota."